# Can't get bluetooth media buttons to work inside the main activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I know there is an implementation to get the bluetooth media buttons for android MediaPlayer however I'm using the MediaPlayer inside a service. A service I start and stop from the main activity (which also controls the GUI) by pressing the Start and Stop button.

Here it is my main activity. I will try to add only the required code for this problem since my main activity is quite big.

```
public class homepage extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initializeUIElements();
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        final PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WakeLock:Acquire");
        wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000 L);
        Timer wakeLockTimer = new Timer();
        wakeLockTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    wakeLock.release();
                    if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                        wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000 L);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 0, 10 * 60 * 1000);
    }
    //Headphone button.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                if (!mRunning) {
                    buttonPlayAction();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                if (mRunning) {
                    stopPlaying();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                if (mRunning) {
                    stopPlaying();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                if (!mRunning) {
                    buttonPlayAction();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    stopPlaying();
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use `buttonPlayAction();`which is the Play button and `stopPlaying();` which is the Stop button through the bluetooth media buttons. These two buttons starts and stops the MediaPlayer service so I must do it here rather than do it inside the service. The MediaPlayer is required to be inside a service so that it runs in the background but I must control the start and stop buttons from inside the main activity because I need to change the button's behaviour once they're pressed which I can't do from the service itself.

The problem is, it doesn't work. My app works from API 21 and newer so it's the newer implementation of the media buttons. I know that before API 21, the implementation was different. Everything I've looked for online leads to the old implementation. I did this myself following the official informations.

Is there something I've missed? I've also set the user permissions for internet (since this is an app for an internet radio stream), bluetooth and wake lock.